# From GCS_WGS_1984 to ED 1950 33N: no suitable transformation in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I have downloaded a bathymetric dataset from this web site (http://portal.emodnet-bathymetry.eu/#) in GeoTIFF format. It uses GCS_WGS_1984 coordinate system.

I have to make the dataset match the coordinate system of a DTM I have, which uses [European Datum 1950, UTM 33N](https://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::23033). In ArcGIS (10.1), I tried the 'Project Raster' facility, but it does need me to specify a geographic transformation to be selected from a drop-down menu. There seems to be no transformation suitable from the task at hand.

How can I project the bathymetric dataset to match the DTM, given the absence (in ArcGIS 10.1 at least) of a suitable transformation?

Comment: 10.1 is ancient software. Recent questions indicate that such transformations are now possible.

Comment: If you add it to ArcMap, do you get any transformations there? It's possible that this bathymetric data is outside the areas-of-use for the ED50-WGS84 transformations. If you can get a transformation in ArcMap, export the raster from there using the data frame's coordinate system.

Answer (score 1):

ED_1950_To_WGS_1984_1 is a general transformation for Western Europe.  It will give you accuracy to within 10 meters.

Descriptions of other transformations for ArcMap 10.1 can be found here: http://downloads2.esri.com/support/TechArticles/Geographic_Transformations_10.1.zip

Answer (score 0):

Without ArcGIS you could try [GDAL](https://www.gdal.org/index.html) utilities.  A command like the below should work:

```
gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:23033 emodnet.tiff outputfile.tiff
```